# Angular 6 - Email Pattern Validation not working in Component

Tags: angular6

I am using Regex "^[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$" which perfectly matches valid emails on Online RegexTester but same is not working in angular component.

angular.component.ts:

```
let emailRegex = new RegExp("^[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$");
else if(this.webBillingUser.email && !this.webBillingUser.email.match(emailRegex)){
        this.alertService.warning('Invalid email address.', null, null);
        return false;
 }
```

Please suggest what could be wrong.

Comment: I think you should edit your regex to this :
`let emailRegex = new RegExp("/^[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/");`

Comment: Perfect, worked like charm. Thank you!!

Comment: Could you mark my comment as an answer?

Comment: This change was failing for valid EmailId's too.This regex works perfectly fine:
^[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$